# Is it "more dangerous" or "the most dangerous" in "Un prisonnier des plus dangereux"?

Tags: sens, prépositions, articles, comparatifs, superlatifs

> Un prisonnier **des** plus dangereux, Edmond Dantès.

As I understand, "plus dangereux" means "more dangerous" and "le plus dangereux" means "the most dangerous". But what is the use of the article "des" here? How should I understand the sentence above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Des plus dangereux* means *parmi les plus dangereux*:

> A prisoner considered amongst the most dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

*Des plus* signifie *très*. *Des plus* est quasiment toujours suivi d'un adjectif au pluriel.

> C'est un prisonnier des plus dangereux : c'est un prisonnier très dangereux.

Changer l'ordre des mots dans cette phrase change aussi sa signification.

> C'est un des plus dangereux prisonniers ; c'est un des prisonniers les plus dangereux : he is one of the most dangerous prisonners.